# thead-dark not work in angular project using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I try to add `thead-dark` into my table but is does not work. I'm using bootstrap.

My code:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Units In Stock</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Bootstrap :

```
....
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
....
```

It's last version of bootstrap not support thead-dark?

How to proceed?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. In latest version of bootstrap, we can use "table-dark" class instead of "thead-dark". You can use "table-dark" class in `thead`, `tr`, and `td` also.

Please refer to this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/qomrf9pk/

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Units In Stock</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Demo Name</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    ...
  </thead>
   <tbody>
   ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nNJ4.png)

Answer (score 4):

As the other guy said up top, seems like they didn't update their doc on the https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/

"table-dark" is the correct one

Comment: They also didn't update this part for versions up to 5.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Use "table-dark" instead of "thead-dark" .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).